# JAVA if statement with array not working

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I'm trying to build a book ticket system but my code is not working properly, there is no error just the result I'm expected cannot get 
here is my code, can any tell me where is wrong with my code?

```
 public class Train  {
 public static void book(){

 int dest,sno;
 char[] seat1=new char [9];

 Integer Tid=1;

 Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
 Scanner sc2=new Scanner(System.in);
 for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
{
    seat1[i]='A';
}
 System.out.println("Where do you want to go?");
  System.out.println("1. Main Entrerance to Night Safari");
  System.out.println("2. Main Enterance to River Safari");
  System.out.println("3. River Safari to Main Enterance");
  dest=sc.nextInt();
if (dest==1 && Tid !=null)
  {
System.out.println("_1"+seat1[0]+"_|_2"+seat1[1]+"_|_3"+seat1[2]+"_");
  System.out.println("_4"+seat1[3]+"_|_5"+seat1[4]+"_|_6"+seat1[5]+"_");     
  System.out.println("_7"+seat1[6]+"_|_8"+seat1[7]+"_|_9"+seat1[8]+"_");
  System.out.println("Enter seat number to select seat:");
  sno=sc.nextInt();

  if(sno>=1 && sno<=9)
{
    if(seat1[sno-1]!='B')
    {

        seat1[sno-1]='B';

        book();//here is working, it will go back again but when I re enter book(); and select dest1 agn it doesn't changed selected sno to B
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("Seat Already Booked, Choose Another ");

       book();
    }

}
}

else
{
    System.out.println("Invalid Seat Number, Select Again ");

    book();
}
}
}
```

the output is show as I expected like

*1A*|_2A_|*3A*
_4A_|*5A*|_6A_
*7A*|_8A_|*9A*
but when I select a seat and return to it again, it didn't change the selected seat from A to B as I expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix. You use the recursive approach with the method `book()`. You wish to edit to the array `seat1` but each time you call the method `book()` the array gets recreated with initial values.

A fix would be to make another method that gets called once before calling the first `book()` method like so:

```
public static void initArray() {
     for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
     {
        seat1[i]='A';
     }
}
```

and then remove the creation of the array in the book method.

Note: You will have to make the array `char[] seat1=new char [9];` an attribute of the class by putting `private static char[] seat1=new char [9];` under `public class Train {`

**UPDATE:**
Entire class updated:

```
package javaapplication19;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Train {

    static char[] seat1 = new char[9];

    public static void book() {

        int dest, sno;

        Integer Tid = 1;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Where do you want to go?");
        System.out.println("1. Main Entrerance to Night Safari");
        System.out.println("2. Main Enterance to River Safari");
        System.out.println("3. River Safari to Main Enterance");
        dest = sc.nextInt();
        if (dest == 1 && Tid != null) {
            System.out.println("_1" + seat1[0] + "_|_2" + seat1[1] + "_|_3" + seat1[2] + "_");
            System.out.println("_4" + seat1[3] + "_|_5" + seat1[4] + "_|_6" + seat1[5] + "_");
            System.out.println("_7" + seat1[6] + "_|_8" + seat1[7] + "_|_9" + seat1[8] + "_");
            System.out.println("Enter seat number to select seat:");
            sno = sc.nextInt();

            if (sno >= 1 && sno <= 9) {
                if (seat1[sno - 1] != 'B') {

                    seat1[sno - 1] = 'B';

                    book();//here is working, it will go back again but when I re enter book(); and select dest1 agn it doesn't changed selected sno to B
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Seat Already Booked, Choose Another ");

                    book();
                }

            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Seat Number, Select Again ");

            book();
        }
    }

    public static void init() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            seat1[i] = 'A';
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives the following output:

> run:
>
> Where do you want to go?
>
> 1. Main Entrerance to Night Safari
> 2. Main Enterance to River Safari
> 3. River Safari to Main Enterance
>
> 1
>
> *1A*|_2A_|*3A*
>
> *4A*|_5A_|*6A*
>
> *7A*|_8A_|*9A*
>
> Enter seat number to select seat:
>
> 2
>
> Where do you want to go?
>
> 1. Main Entrerance to Night Safari
> 2. Main Enterance to River Safari
> 3. River Safari to Main Enterance
>
> 1
>
> *1A*|_2B_|*3A*
>
> *4A*|_5A_|*6A*
>
> *7A*|_8A_|*9A*
>
> Enter seat number to select seat:

Is this not what you wanted?

Comment: Thx man =D
now the B is showing but A is missing 
_1B_|_2B_|_3 _

Comment: yaya, Thanks a lot!! can you help me to understand why it when I put the initial array at above of book() method?